# Python function to upload files to storage failing with 403 TooManyDevicesError

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have a python app running on an embedded linux device. The app runs async code that connects an iothub device client. I have a class called device_client_wrapper that uses a semaphore to ensure that only one function calls device client methods at a time, as that was causing me issues before.

I just added a new function to this class which is used to upload files from the device to azure blob storage. It was working fine for a while, and often works the first time, but then if I execute it too many times I get the following error:

```
ERROR upload_file Exception: Unexpected failure
ERROR Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/aio/async_clients.py", line 33, in handle_result
    return await callback.completion()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/iot/device/common/async_adapter.py", line 91, in completion
    return await self.future
azure.iot.device.exceptions.ServiceError: HTTP operation returned: 403 TooManyDevicesError(Error: Forbidden)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/cogo_ig60/cloud/device_client_wrapper.py", line 99, in upload_file
    blob_info = await self.device_client.get_storage_info_for_blob(blob_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/aio/async_clients.py", line 571, in get_storage_info_for_blob
    storage_info = await handle_result(callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/aio/async_clients.py", line 57, in handle_result
    raise exceptions.ClientError("Unexpected failure") from e
azure.iot.device.exceptions.ClientError: Unexpected failure
```

This is the function causing the error:

```
async def upload_file(self, path_to_file: str, blob_name: str):
    """Upload a file to Azure Blob Storage."""
    try:
        async with self.semaphore:
            blob_info = await self.device_client.get_storage_info_for_blob(blob_name)
            sas_url = "https://{}/{}/{}{}".format(
                blob_info["hostName"],
                blob_info["containerName"], 
                blob_info["blobName"],
                blob_info["sasToken"]
            )
            logger.info(
                f"Uploading file {path_to_file} to blob storage as {blob_name}")
            with BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url) as blob_client:
                with open(path_to_file, "rb") as f:
                    result = blob_client.upload_blob(f, overwrite=True)
                    return (True, result)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        # catch file not found and add an HTTP status code to return in notification to IoT Hub
        logger.error(f'upload_file FileNotFoundError: {e}')
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        e.status_code = 404
        return (False, e)
    except AzureError as e:
        # catch Azure errors that might result from the upload operation
        logger.error(f'upload_file AzureError: {e}')
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        return (False, e)
    except Exception as e:
        # catch all other errors
        logger.error(f'upload_file Exception: {e}')
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        return (False, e)
```

It seems to be an issue with device_client.get_storage_info_for_blob. I know there are a max of 10 concurrent file uploads per device, but I am uploading 7 fiiles, then they finish uploading successfully before I try again. Even so, with the semaphore it should prevent any concurrent file uploads. That is unless I'm missing something about how my code is working.

Is something not being released properly, or not able to complete properly?

This is python 3.10.4 btw.

Comment: Anyone? I could really use some help on this

Comment: Related Github link: [Upload files to storage failing with 403 TooManyDevicesError](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/1097)

Related thread: [Python function to upload files to storage failing with 403 TooManyDevicesError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167060/python-function-to-upload-files-to-storage-failing)

Comment: Hi @Locks, I notice that you are calling the method device_client.get_storage_info_for_blob each time your are uploading the file. It would be beneficial to pull this information once in the main method or outside this async code block and pass the value as a parameter to this method. The objective is to not hit this method for every file upload.

Comment: You can change the method definition to something like this `async def upload_file(self, path_to_file: str, blob_info)`. Get the storage information using the command `storage_info = device_client.get_storage_info_for_blob(blob_name)` and call the upload_file method as follows `success, result = store_blob(self, PATH_TO_FILE, storage_info)` Please refer the code sample in [Upload a file from a device app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-python-file-upload#upload-a-file-from-a-device-app) for reference.

Comment: But the device_client.get_storage_info_for_blob takes the blob name as an argument. Each time I'm calling this it's uploading a different file, so a different blob name.

Answer (score 0):

Found additional information indicating the potential cause of this issue. Posting it here incase other community members encounter this behavior.

Each device is limited to 10 concurrent active file uploads at a time. In addition to that there is additional throttling applied to IoT Hub based on the SKU and the number of units available. For example, S1 tier has a limit of 1.67 file upload initiations/sec/unit. Suppose you have an S1 tier of units, you would hit the throttling limit at 6.67 file uploads per second.

Please refer the following documentation for reference.

- [File upload quotas and limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload#file-upload-quotas-and-limits)
- [Basic and standard tier operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#basic-and-standard-tier-operations)